# NoRM UpdateOne no work

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm

I'm using NoRM + MongoDB in an application test. I found the source code of the Mongo Session http://normproject.org/samples where the method update wrapp this:

```
using(var db = Mongo.Create(_connectionString))
{
  db.GetCollection<T>().UpdateOne(item, item);
}
```

But when I send object to update using this method my object no save, but what if I call Save instead of UpdateOne my object is save.

My objects: https://gist.github.com/1616565

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps:
http://groups.google.com/group/norm-mongodb/browse_thread/thread/8ba8b462b6fe16a5/a4bfaecef4b1cbfc?lnk=gst&q=Update#a4bfaecef4b1cbfc

Anup

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the official C# driver, which you can find at:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center